# Move comments to chat for extended discussion is not working

Tags: bug, status-review, comments

When I saw this message [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/313552/18673):

> Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?

I would obviously click it due to avoiding long comments, but nothing happened after I clicked it, and it just redirected me to the top of the question page

*There was no link to the discussion found in any comments*

And the page said "Moving the discussion to chat failed"

Is this a bug?

Comment: @Glorfindel i have encountered the same problem [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/313610/as-if-you-have-seen-the-ghost-saw-the-ghost/313613) again just now

Comment: I wanted to confirm - there was a notice saying that moving to chat failed? Or not? It's a bit confusing because you say it just redirected you to the top of the page - which does happen when there's an error but we've had some of our error messages disappear, so I'm trying to determine whether the issue is the explanation being missing or migrating to chat being broken or both.

Comment: Or my bad @Catija, the message will first show up. After clicking the 2nd or 3rd time, it will start redirecting you to the top of the page (redirects half the time only). Note redirecting in this case meant that the page did not reload, and just sent me back up to top of page